# Each iteration, delay the execution

Tags: jquery

```
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        (function(index) {

           ajaxFuncHere(i);


            //now you can also loop an ajax call here without problems: $.ajax({});
        })(i);

    }
```

I would like to delay each iteration with say 300 ms or something, how can I do that?

I tried putting a setTimeout like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        (function(index) {

          setTimeout(function () {
           ajaxFuncHere(i);
          }, 300);          

            //now you can also loop an ajax call here without problems: $.ajax({});
        })(i);

    }
```

However its not giving me the desired result, but instead just delaying and then put them all out.

How can I delay each iteration with 300 ms after the function itself is completed, (the reason I use the closure within)

Comment: setTimeOut() doesn't stop processing, it just says "do this function in X ms".

Answer (score 1):

Delay them incrementally.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    (function(index) {

      setTimeout(function () {
       ajaxFuncHere(index);
      }, 300*(index+1));

    })(i);
}
```

Comment: It seems like when using it, it scopes it away too far as if i add the setTimeout the inner function fails to do its task, and if removed it works

Comment: @John Use `index` instead of `i` inside the anonymous function: `setTimeout(function() { ajaxFuncHere(index); }, 300*(index+1));`.

Comment: @freakish indeed, thanks for the correction. Edited now.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to use a multiplication :

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    (function(index) {

      setTimeout(function () {
       ajaxFuncHere(index);
      }, 300 * 1);       //Will delay the script   

        //now you can also loop an ajax call here without problems: $.ajax({});
    })(i);

}
```

The best solution is to use the ajax done callback with a self-calling function. Since i dont know how your `ajaxFuncHere`look like, ill asume something like this :

```
function ajaxFuncHere(){
    $.ajax(...);
}
```

Change it for that :

```
function ajaxFuncHere(){
    return $.ajax(...);
}
```

then Use something like that :

```
//Remove the for
(function loop(number, current) {

    if(current === undefined) current = 0;

    if(current < number) setTimeout(function () {
        ajaxFuncHere(current).done(loop.bind(null, number, ++current));
    }, 300);          
})(5); //5 == number of iteration
```

Once the ajax is done, it will recall the function and wait 300 ms.

Comment: It works the first iteration, and then it says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'done' of undefined

Comment: @John place the keyword `return` before `$.getJSON` : `return $.getJSON()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the for-loop with a [tail-recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion) which timeouts at the end of it's execution and calls itself again:

```
var i = 0;
var max = 5;
var doLoop = function()
{
    if(i < max)
    {
        ajaxFuncHere(i);
        i++;
        setTimeout(doLoop, 1000);
    }
};
doLoop();

function ajaxFuncHere(x)
{
    // Do what you want to do.
    // Look at the demo for an example.
}
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Hu55F/). Just replace your `ajaxFuncHere` with mine and it should work just fine.